# How find out which stylesheets were applied (check via javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have two stylesheets set with media queries:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (min-width: 64.1em)' href='desktop.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (max-width: 64em)' href='mobile.css' />
```

And I'm looking for a class in `document.styleSheets`, how would I be able to ignore the non-active stylesheet?

For example:

```
//Pseudo-code
for ( var i = 0; i < document.styelSheets.length; i++ ) if ( document.styelSheets[ i ].isApplied ) ...
```

Is there a way to know?

Comment: Well, why don't you just just get the size of the window in JS?

Comment: There isn't a definitive way to tell. Technically, they would be both always be applied. The easiest thing to do is compare against a static css value that you know would be present for one media or another (e.g. width).

Comment: There isn't a definitive way to tell. Technically, they would be both always be applied. The easiest thing to do is compare against a static css value that you know would be present for one media or another (e.g. width).

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice Js feature called `window.matchMedia()`, that can be used to test if a certain media query matches to the viewport, for example:

```
if(window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 64.1em)').matches) {
    //match
}
else {
    //don't match
}
```

If you can iterate through all link tags, you could test each `media` attribute and check if it is applied.

[**MDN .matchMedia() docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)

Comment: that requires IE10 or later. I need IE8+